# state chart xml processor in JavaScript for browser applications

Tags: javascript, processor, scxml

i need a State Chart XML processor in Javascript, to run single players applications on the browser. Does someone know, if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

There is SCION SCXML https://gitlab.com/scion-scxml/scion
Disclaimer: I am the author.